# PHP split and mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, foreach

ok, this might sound strange, but i have a form and our business wants to track what is getting changed, when a user adds a new lead etc.

So i set up a function that does the following

```
function savedata($data){
    $collection = $this->db->retail_logs;
    $this->data = explode('|', $data['data']);
    print_r($this->data);

    try {
    $collection->update(
        array($this->data['0']=>$this->data['1'],$this->data[2]=>$this->data[3]),
        array("date"=> date("d.m.Y"), "time"=>date("H:i:s"),"whochanged"=>$_COOKIE['CRMUIDkey']), // new lead document to insert
        array("upsert" => true, "safe" => true)
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Something went wrong .. 
    }
}
```

it is basiclly a log file.

but as you may be able to see the $data sends data though like tradingname|ABC|owner|ownerID

But if I want to add to that i would need to run a loop or a foreach I am wondering what is the best way to make sure all teh data gets saved and not just data[0] to 3 so say they send 16 fields and values in it I need a foreach or something to split it.

Comment: Did you find my approach useful?  Notice you haven't accepted many answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you want to map the `$data['data']` into key=>value pairs (an associative array). You want to be very careful about what fields you allow in this format especially since it looks like user-provided data (or data they can modify in a post request?).  For example, a malicious user could update or add to another user's account if you aren't checking the allowed keys before doing the upsert.

To convert the `$data` string you want to do something like:

```
<?php
    // Keys that can be updated
    $allowed = array('tradingname','owner');

    // Sample data    
    $data = 'tradingname|ABC|owner|ownerID|badkey|foo';

    // Split into arrays based on '|' delimiter
    preg_match_all("/([^\|]+)\|([^\|]+)/", $data, $keypairs);

    // Combine matches into key => value array
    $keypairs = array_combine($keypairs[1], $keypairs[2]);

    // Sanity check to create $criteria    
    foreach ($keypairs as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($key, $allowed)) {
            // Perhaps do some extra sanity checking that $value is expected format
            $criteria[$key] = $value;
        } else {
            // Log and/or bailout as appropriate
            echo "Ignoring: [$key] => [$value]\n";
        }
    }

    // Criteria should now be reasonable to use in $collection->update(..) upsert
    print_r($criteria);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Send your data as json. And then use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert it to the array you want.

Comment: How would i do that when its I need it to send every time a user changes an input or select value is there a javascript form post function i run